# A program in C++ involving pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I cannot understand the output of this program:

```
void main(){
    double d=3.1416;
    char ch=*(char*)&d;
    cout<<ch;
    }
```

OUTPUT: 2

Note: The 2 is of much smaller size than the usual 2.

Can you please explain the meaning of line 3.
Thank You.

Comment: What does your Note mean?  Have you made any attempt to understand this yourself?

Comment: To print out the pointer address use `cout<<(void*)ch;`. That line is pretty meaningless from that context though.

Comment: Do you mean the 2 you're seeing is a superscript 2?

Comment: You can't learn `C++` by picking up random pieces of code that you don't understand and asking people on the internet to explain them. You need to apply yourself to a course or a book that explains everything from the beginning. Recommended books: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Yes, the 2 is a superscript of 2.

Answer (score 1):

In your statement:

```
char ch=*(char*)&d;
```

You are performing the following:
1. Taking the address or location of the variable.
2. Creating a pointer of type character to point to the variable.
3. Dereferencing (converting the first location of the variable) to a type of character (no transformations have occurred yet.
4. Assigning the first memory location of `d` to a character type variable (no conversions yet).

You are then printing the value in `ch`.

If the value in `ch` is a printable value, you are in luck; however, I doubt it will be meaningful.  Otherwise, you won't be able to see it.

If you want to convert or transform from internal representation to textual representation, use:

```
cout << d;
```

I highly recommend using a debugger on this code and view the memory location of variable `d`.  Take the value and see if it is printable.

**Edit 1:**
The value printed in line 4 depends on how the value `3.1416` is stored in memory.

Since it is a floating point variable, we can guess that it is split into:  sign, mantissa and exponent.  The big question, is how many bits are dedicated to the three groups.  Usually, one bit is the sign.  The others depend on your platform.  If the `char` type on your platform is 8 bit, and the order is mantissa, exponent, then sign, your character will be the first 8 bits of the mantissa, which is probably not a printable character.